# Relacionar 3 tabelas numa dispensação de medicamentos?

Tags: php, foreach

Estou fazendo um sistema para a minha farmácia: dispensação de medicamentos com receita controlado.

Fiz a tabela **pacientes** (id, nome, cpf, telefone, endereço, foto_documento), **dispensação** (id_paciente, id_medicamento, quantidade, crm, data_receita, data_dispensacao, foto_receita) e **medicamentos** (id, medicamento, laboratorio).

Só quem quando vou fazer a listagem, queria que todos os medicamentos da mesma receita, para o mesmo paciente, com o mesmo CRM, na mesma data de receita e dispensação.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'init.php';

$sql = "SELECT *, pacientes.id AS id_pac FROM pacientes INNER JOIN dispensacao ON pacientes.id = dispensacao.id_paciente INNER JOIN medicamentos ON medicamentos.id = dispensacao.id_medicamento ORDER BY nome";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($ln = $query->fetch_array()){

$id_pac = $ln['id_pac'];
$nome_pac = $ln['nome'];
$cpf = $ln['cpf'];
$tel = $ln['telefone'];
$end = $ln['endereco'];
$imgdocumento = $ln['documento'];
$crm = $ln['crm'];
$data_receita = $ln['data_receita'];
$data_dispensacao = $ln['data_dispensacao'];
$imgreceita = $ln['receita'];
$nome_medic = $ln['medicamento'];
$qnt = $ln['quantidade'];

echo '<li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-content item-link">
                        <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="item-title"><i class="icon f7-icons size-22">person</i> '.$nome_pac.'</div>
                        </div></a>
                      <div class="accordion-item-content">
                        <div class="content-block">
                            <p><hr></p>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">sort</i> <b>CPF</b></div>
                                <div class="col-50">'.$cpf.'</div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">phone</i> <b>Telefone</b></div>
                                <div class="col-50">'.$tel.'</div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">compose</i> <b>Endereço</b></div>
                                <div class="col-50">'.$end.'</div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">today</i> <b>Data da Receita</b></div>
                                <div class="col-50"><a href="#" class="data-vencimento">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data_receita)).'</a></div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">today_fill</i> <b>Data da Dispensação</b></div>
                                <div class="col-50">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data_dispensacao)).'</div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">card</i> <b>CRM</b></div>
                                <div class="col-50">'.$crm.'</div>
                              </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                      <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">list</i> <b>Medicamentos Dispensados</b></div>
                      <div class="col-50">
                        <div class="data-table card centralized">
                          <table>
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th class="label-cell">Medicamento</th>
                                <th class="numeric-cell">Quantidade</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="list_med">';

                             <tr>
                              <td class="label-cell">'.$nome_med.'</td>
                              <td class="numeric-cell">'.$qnt.'</td>
                             </tr>   


                            echo '</tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                      <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">images</i> <b>Receita</b></div>
                      <div class="col-50"><img src="receitas/'.$imgreceita.'" width="50" height="50"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                      <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">images_fill</i> <b>Documento</b></div>
                      <div class="col-50"><img src="receitas/'.$imgdocumento.'" width="50" height="50"></div>
                    </div>';
}
```

Não estou encontrando uma solução para a minha listagem. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Resultado até agora: www.blocodochapolin.com.br/FP_novo/pacientes.php

O resultado que quero chegar seria esse: http://blocodochapolin.com.br/FP_novo/

Lista de Pacientes

Ex: um paciente pode ter várias receitas, e cada receita seria uma list com os medicamentos dessa receita (dispensacao).

Comment: Escuta, não entendi muito bem a questão, principalmente em relação ao termo dispensação. De todo jeito, o que entendi é que você quer que a listagem mostre a relação de medicamentos por cada dispensação dessa do link? Se for isso, você pode fazer o join da tabela medicamento no sql mostrado, para recuperar o nome do mesmo

Comment: Desse jeito que falei você vai ter a mesma informação de paciente e dispensação sendo repetida para cada medicamento, então você vai ter que agrupar depois. Se for esse o caso, é só falar que eu formulo uma resposta para a questão

Comment: Dispensação é o termo técnico de vender o remédio para uma pessoa. Como seria esse agrupamento?

Comment: Opa, acabei de ver que a tabela medicamento já está no join

Comment: Sim, mas olha o resultado: ele mostra o mesmo paciente 2x, e os medicamentos 2x. 
Queria que mostrasse o paciente, e os medicamentos dispensados para ele na mesma consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acessei o link que você deixou e aparentemente você conseguiu resolver o problema, mas de qualquer forma vou postar uma forma de solucionar isso pois pode ajudar outros membros.

A primeira alteração que eu fiz, foi agrupar os resultados pelo `id` do paciente. Para trazer todos os medicamentos e quantidades, usei a função `GROUP_CONCAT` do `MySql`, esta função é responsável por agrupar as linhas concatenando em uma única célula. Já no `PHP`, usei a função `explode` para quebrar esta célula em um `array`, fiz a mesma coisa com as quantidades, depois disso, foi só fazer um `for` para varrer o array e escrever as informações.

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

  include 'init.php';

  $sql = "
    SELECT a.id, a.nome, a.cpf, a.telefone, a.endereco, a.documento, a.documento
    FROM pacientes a
  ";
  $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

  while($ln = $query->fetch_array()){
    echo '
      <li class="accordion-item">
        <a href="#" class="item-content item-link">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title"><i class="icon f7-icons size-22">person</i> '.$ln['nome'].'</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="accordion-item-content">
          <div class="content-block">
            <p><hr></p>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">sort</i> <b>CPF</b></div>
              <div class="col-50">'.$ln['cpf'].'</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">phone</i> <b>Telefone</b></div>
              <div class="col-50">'.$ln['telefone'].'</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">compose</i> <b>Endereço</b></div>
              <div class="col-50">'.$ln['endereco'].'</div>
            </div>
    ';

    $sql = "
      SELECT a.crm, a.data_receita, a.data_dispensacao, a.receita,
      GROUP_CONCAT(b.medicamento SEPARATOR '|||') medicamentos, GROUP_CONCAT(b.quantidade SEPARATOR '|||') quantidades
      FROM dispensacao a
      INNER JOIN medicamentos b ON b.id = a.id_medicamento
      WHERE a.id_paciente = '.$ln['id'].'
      GROUP BY a.id
      ORDER BY a.nome
    ";
    $query1 = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while($lnReceita = $query1->fetch_array()){

      echo '
            <p><hr></p>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">today</i> <b>Data da Receita</b></div>
              <div class="col-50"><a href="#" class="data-vencimento">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($lnReceita['data_receita'])).'</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">today_fill</i> <b>Data da Dispensação</b></div>
              <div class="col-50">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($lnReceita['data_dispensacao'])).'</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">card</i> <b>CRM</b></div>
              <div class="col-50">'.$lnReceita['crm'].'</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">list</i> <b>Medicamentos Dispensados</b></div>
                <div class="col-50">
                  <div class="data-table card centralized">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="label-cell">Medicamento</th>
                          <th class="numeric-cell">Quantidade</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id="list_med">
      ';

      $medicamentos = explode('|||', $lnReceita['medicamentos']);
      $quantidades = explode('|||', $lnReceita['quantidades']);
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($medicamentos); $i++) {
        echo '
          <tr>
            <td class="label-cell">'.$medicamentos[$i].'</td>
            <td class="numeric-cell">'.$quantidades[$i].'</td>
          </tr>
      }

      echo '
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">images</i> <b>Receita</b></div>
                <div class="col-50"><img src="receitas/'.$lnReceita['receita'].'" width="50" height="50"></div>
              </div>
      ';
    }

    echo '
              <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">images_fill</i> <b>Documento</b></div>
                <div class="col-50"><img src="receitas/'.$ln['documento'].'" width="50" height="50"></div>
              </div>
    ';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Segue o seu SELECT consertado: `SELECT a.id as id_pac, a.nome, a.cpf, a.telefone, a.endereco, a.documento, b.crm, b.data_receita, b.data_dispensacao, b.receita,
    a.documento, GROUP_CONCAT(c.medicamento SEPARATOR '|||') medicamentos, GROUP_CONCAT(b.quantidade SEPARATOR '|||') quantidades
    FROM pacientes a
    INNER JOIN dispensacao b ON a.id = b.id_paciente
    INNER JOIN medicamentos c ON c.id = b.id_medicamento
    GROUP BY a.id
    ORDER BY a.nome`

Comment: Só tem um problema: se eu tiver uma nova receita, do mesmo paciente, com outra data, outro CRM e outros medicamentos, teria que aparecer outro dado dele, numa nova list!

Comment: O `AS` não é necessário para a consulta funcionar, os campos `foto_receita` e `foto_documento` foram os que você colocou na sua pergunta. Para corrigir o problema da segunda receita, basta colocar um campo `id` na tabela `dispensacao` e fazer o `SELECT` da seguinte forma:

Comment: `SELECT a.id id_pac, a.nome, a.cpf, a.telefone, a.endereco, a.documento, b.crm, b.data_receita, b.data_dispensacao, b.receita, a.documento, GROUP_CONCAT(c.medicamento SEPARATOR '|||') medicamentos, GROUP_CONCAT(b.quantidade SEPARATOR '|||') quantidades FROM pacientes a INNER JOIN dispensacao b ON a.id = b.id_paciente INNER JOIN medicamentos c ON c.id = b.id_medicamento GROUP BY a.id, b.id ORDER BY a.nome`

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo, mas é quase isso. Sobre os campos, eu tinha colocado errado, me desculpe.
No caso, lá na página, está exibindo um campo por medicamento.

1 paciente pode ter X receitas, com Y medicamentos em cada.

Teria que ser junto: os medicamentos de cada receita, com cada CRM, com cada Data. É nisso que estou quebrando a cabeça!

Comment: Não entendi, pode editar sua pergunta e colocar um exemplo de como você quer que fique a listagem?

Comment: Editei lá @RobertoFagundes

Comment: Agora consegui entender o que você precisa, para fazer isso seria melhor fazer dois `SELECT`, pode ser?

Comment: Sem problemas!!

Comment: Alterei o código da resposta, verifique se funciona, não consigo testar pois não tenho sua base de dados

Comment: Amigo, sei que estou torrando a sua paciencia, mas ainda não é isso! Olha lá no link como está!

No caso, quando for a mesma receita, os medicamentos tem que estar juntos.

Comment: Consegui!! Mudei o seu select para esse: `SELECT a.crm, a.data_receita, a.data_dispensacao, a.receita, GROUP_CONCAT(b.medicamento SEPARATOR '|||') medicamentos, GROUP_CONCAT(a.quantidade SEPARATOR '|||') quantidades FROM dispensacao a INNER JOIN medicamentos b ON b.id = a.id_medicamento WHERE a.id_paciente = {$ln['id']} GROUP BY data_receita`
Obrigado @RobertoFernanes

Comment: Por favor, poste no site SqlFiddle a estrutura e os dados da sua tabela

Comment: blz, que bom que conseguiu